# C++ Pulling information and looping to display

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Not under standing looping for arrays. Looping through all of grab some or search. Can someone explain the process? Thanks in advance. Sorry if duplicate. I looked around and couldnt find a solid explaination that I could understand.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void allContacts(string names[], string phones[])
{
    cout << "Showing all contacts... Press Q to go back to main menu" << endl;
}

void addName(string names[], string phones[])
{
    bool keepGoing;
    string input;

    beginning:
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter contact name: ";
        cin >> names[i];
        cout << "Enter contact number: ";
        cin >> phones[i];
        cout << "Do you have another contact to add? y or no" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        if(input == "y" || input == "Y")
        {
            goto beginning;
        }

        if(input == "n" || input == "N")
        {
            cout << "Contacts you have entered: " << endl;
            cout << names[i] << " : " << phones[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void searchName(string names[], string phones[])
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter Name: ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Search for a name or Press Q to go back to main menu" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++){
        if (name == names[i])
        {
            cout << counter << names[i] << " 's phone number is: " << phones[i] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "No results found";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string names[100];
    string phones[100];
    int choice;

    cout << "============================" << endl;
    cout << "=== Welcome to PhoneBook ===" << endl;
    cout << "============================" << endl;

    cout << "1- Add a New Contact" << endl;
    cout << "2- Search By Name" << endl;
    cout << "3- Display All" << endl;
    cout << "0- Exit" << endl;

    cout << "Select a number: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        addName(names, phones);
        break;
    case 2:
        searchName(names, phones);
        break;
    case 3:
        allContacts(names, phones);
        break;
    case 0:
        cout << "Exiting PhoneBook...";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What part of the code is it that you don't understand ?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(names); i++)` isn't correct. `sizeof` will return the size of a `string*` (in bytes), not a size of the array. Read up on `sizeof` operator, and passing arrays to functions (and array decaying).

Comment: You have a `goto` that goes backwards, and it jumps from inside a loop to a place before it. Please don't do that. `goto` should be used in **very** limited circumstances. This is not one of them. That said... What is your question exactly?

Comment: Read up on `continue` and `break` statements.  They would resolve your `goto` issue.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` and just add as many conacts as you like without any size checking while adding data.

Comment: Or at least use `std::array`....

Comment: Some info on ["What is array decaying"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: My question is when looping through arrays, what does all the information in the loop mean, so I can use to make search and show all and save etc.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ arrays lose attributes when passed to functions.  Those attributes are capacity and size (number of filled slots).  You will need to pass this additional information for each array:

```
void addName(string names[],  unsigned int names_capacity, unsigned int names_size,
 string phones[], unsigned int phones_capacity, unsigned int phones_size)
```

To get around this, you can use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` knows its capacity and size, so you don't have to pass additional attributes to your function.

Also, if you use `tolower` or `toupper` before you compare, you only need to make one comparison:

```
char input; 
cout << "Do you have another contact to add? y or n" << endl;
cin >> input;
input = toupper(input);
if(input == 'Y')
```

When using strings, you can convert them to all uppercase or all lowercase by using `std::transform`, such as:

```
  std::transform(input.begin(),
                 input.begin(), input.end(),
                 tolower);
```

Comment: Ok lets say they say yes, would would I use to go back to start the loop again?